# Alpha_vantage produces error

Tags: python-3.x

Alpha_vantage produces an error. Any ideas?

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd

print('Pandas_Version: ' + pd.__version__)

symbol = 'GOOGL'

ts = TimeSeries(key='4BTFICZGTPWZRRQS', output_format='pandas')
close = ts.get_daily(symbol=symbol, outputsize='full')[0]['close']   
direction = (close > close.shift()).astype(int)
target = direction.shift(-1).fillna(0).astype(int)
target.name = 'target'
```

produces error:

Pandas_Version: 0.23.0
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('F:/Eigene Dokumente_C/Documents/AI/Deep_Learning/test_stock_predictor.py',
>   wdir='F:/Eigene Dokumente_C/Documents/AI/Deep_Learning')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Ackermann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Ackermann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "F:/Eigene
>   Dokumente_C/Documents/AI/Deep_Learning/test_stock_predictor.py", line
>   16, in 
>       close = ts.get_daily(symbol=symbol, outputsize='full')[0]['close']   # compact/full
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Ackermann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2685, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Ackermann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2692, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Ackermann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 2486, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Ackermann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 4115, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Ackermann\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 3065, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> KeyError: 'close'

Answer (score 0):

```
close = ts.get_daily(symbol=symbol, outputsize='full')[0]['close']
```

Just delete at the **END** the `['close']`.